# Why don't some of my headers' links work?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a header with 3 navigation links (ul), a logo, and 3 social media icons (ul). All of those elements come with an `<a>` tag but, while the logo and icon's href seem to work just fine, the nav links ones don't and I don't understand why.

```css
#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: rgba($color: #000000, $alpha: .9);
  backdrop-filter: blur(30px);
  min-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: calc(10px + 1vw);
  padding-bottom: calc(10px + 1vw);
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  margin: 0%;
  z-index: 999;
  &:hover {
    cursor: default;
  }
  #navBar {
    float: left;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 2vw;
    z-index: 1000;
    li {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 5px;
      padding-right: 10px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      &:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: $secondary-color;
      }
    }
  }
  #navSocial {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 2vw;
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 15%;
    li {
      margin: auto;
      img {
        height: 30px;
      }
    }
  }
  .logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 47.1vw;
    margin: auto;
    img {
      width: 5vw;
      min-width: 40px;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <ul id="navBar">
    <li>
      <a href="#about"></a>
      <p>About</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#works"></a>
      <p>Works</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#footer"></a>
      <p>Contacts</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a href="" class="logo"><img src="svg/logo.svg" alt="Menu"></a>
  <ul id="navSocial">
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="blank"><img src="svg/instagram.svg" alt="Menu"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="behance.html" target="blank"><img src="svg/behance.svg " alt="Menu"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/"><img src="svg/linkedin.svg" alt="Menu"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the link tags without any text in them:

```
<a href="#about"></a>
```

Directly after the link you have

```
<p>About</p></a>
```

which does have a closing tag `</a>` to which no opening tag exists because the link it was meant to close was closed already before the `<p>` opened.

So correct

```
<a href="#about"></a><p>About</p></a>
<!--             ^^^^ remove the above -->
```

to

```
<a href="#about"><p>About</p></a>
```

Same goes for the other 2 links following your about link.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup as posted is invalid with additional tags such as `</a>`
One benefit of formatting is it shows visually when markup is not properly formed.

Try mouse-over of the links here to see the difference from the original.

I have adjusted your HTML in the snippet here:

```css
#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: rgba($color: #000000, $alpha: .9);
  backdrop-filter: blur(30px);
  min-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: calc(10px + 1vw);
  padding-bottom: calc(10px + 1vw);
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  margin: 0%;
  z-index: 999;
  &:hover {
    cursor: default;
  }
  #navBar {
    float: left;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 2vw;
    z-index: 1000;
    li {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 5px;
      padding-right: 10px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      &:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: $secondary-color;
      }
    }
  }
  #navSocial {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 2vw;
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 15%;
    li {
      margin: auto;
      img {
        height: 30px;
      }
    }
  }
  .logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 47.1vw;
    margin: auto;
    img {
      width: 5vw;
      min-width: 40px;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <ul id="navBar">
    <li>
      <a href="#about">
        <p>About</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#works">
        <p>Works</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#footer">
        <p>Contacts</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a href="" class="logo"><img src="svg/logo.svg" alt="Menu"></a>
  <ul id="navSocial">
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="blank"><img src="svg/instagram.svg" alt="Menu"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="behance.html" target="blank"><img src="svg/behance.svg " alt="Menu"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/"><img src="svg/linkedin.svg" alt="Menu"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Good explanation, anyone learning markup, scripting or any type of coding needs to live structured coding. Not only will it help people debugging your code it will help you to easily spot missing or incorrect items.

Comment: The one addition I would add is placing paragraph <p> inside and anchor <a> is only allowed in HTML 5. I would put the anchor inside the paragraph.

Comment: @DaSmokeDog  Point on the HTML5, but I had to guess the OP's intent there, good comment however.